# ORA-12899: value too large for column COMESFROMTOWN (actual: 50, maximum: 50)

Tags: oracle, varchar, utf-8, nls

I am importing a csv file into an Oracle database using an external table.

The file encoding is `UTF-8`. The separator is actually `;`.

The target table definition is identical to the external table definition.
The `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` is defined as `CHAR`.

Target character fields are defined as `COMESFROMTOWN VARCHAR2(50),` (example).

Reading the external table and loading into the target table works fine for the majority of them. But records with `COMESFROMTOWN` length of 49 to 50 characters including a ',' (comma) are rejected because of length: `ORA-12899: value too large for column COMESFROMTOWN (actual: 50, maximum: 50)`

I tried resizing the external table fields, but the issue also happens when loading the target from the external table. Resizing the target is not an option.

Can you explain why:

- The comma being the 2c `UTF-8` character, coded on 1 byte, it raises an
  error?
- `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` being defined as CHAR, it does not uses
  the requested number of bytes for the string?

How can I workaround this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944757/handling-utf-8-characters-in-oracle-external-tables

Comment: The character must be using up two spaces in the varchar. Increase the size of the column until all the data fits.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **Wernfried Domscheit** suggestion, this solved the issue :

1. `ALTER SESSION SET nls_length_semantics = CHAR` which was decisive
2. `CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1` which exactly fits the source file characterset

Note that our Oracle 11g instance is configured with following defaults:

- NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = CHAR
- NLS_CHARACTERSET = UTF8